# kableExtra:: LaTeX commands are not rendering properly in add_header_above

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kableextra, rnw

I want to use `LaTeX` commands in `add_header_above` function of `kableExtra`

```
library(kableExtra)

x1 <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "html")
add_header_above(x1, c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
add_header_above(x1, c(" ", "\\alpha" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))

x2 <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "latex")
add_header_above(x2, c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
add_header_above(x2, c(" ", "\\alpha" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
```

However, the `LaTeX` command `\\alpha` is not rendering properly. Any solution, please.

**Edited**

```
Test2 <- c(" ", مواطنين = "5", `غير مواطنين` = "6")
Test3 <- c(`\textarabic{}` = " ", `\textarabic{مواطنين}` = "5", 
`\textarabic{غير مواطنين}` = "6")

add_header_above(x1, Test2, escape = FALSE)

add_header_above(x1, Test3, escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: You want alpha to be the greek letter alpha?

Comment: Yes, I want to get greek letter aplha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `escape = FALSE`:

```
add_header_above(x2, c(" ", "$\\\\alpha$" = 5, "Group 2" = 6), escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @snoram for useful answer. Actually I want to mix Arabic with English which creates problem for me. Please see my edits and help me if you can. Thanks